VHDL Floating point multiplier
I'm coding in VHDL a floating point multiplier. This is the code and testbench. The problem is that I'm getting most of the results wrong. What I've observed in the simulation is that it looks like the signals such as sx and sy are delayed by one cycle (This can be seen on the image below). I don't understand why this is happening.
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity multiplier_fp is 
    generic (
        NE: natural := 8;
        NF: natural := 23
    );
    port (
        rst: in std_logic;
        clk: in std_logic;
        x:   in std_logic_vector(NF+NE downto 0);
        y:   in std_logic_vector(NF+NE downto 0);
        z:   out std_logic_vector(NF+NE downto 0)
    );
end multiplier_fp;

architecture behavioral of multiplier_fp is
    constant EXC: signed(NE+1 downto 0) := to_signed(2**(NE-1)-1, NE+2);
    constant ZERO_E: signed(NE-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    constant ZERO_F: unsigned(NF-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal x_reg : std_logic_vector(NF+NE downto 0);
    signal y_reg : std_logic_vector(NF+NE downto 0);
    signal sx : std_logic;
    signal fx : unsigned(NF-1 downto 0);
    signal ex : signed(NE-1 downto 0);
    signal sy : std_logic;
    signal fy : unsigned(NF-1 downto 0);
    signal ey : signed(NE-1 downto 0);
    signal mx : unsigned(NF downto 0);
    signal my : unsigned(NF downto 0);
    signal mz : unsigned(2*NF+1 downto 0);
    signal mz_prev : unsigned(2*NF+1 downto 0);
    signal sz : std_logic;
    signal sx_ex: signed(NE+1 downto 0);
    signal sx_ey: signed(NE+1 downto 0);
    signal ez_prev : signed(NE+1 downto 0);
    signal ez_p2 : signed(NE+1 downto 0);
    signal fz : unsigned(NF-1 downto 0);
    signal ez : signed(NE-1 downto 0);

begin

    process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            x_reg <= (others => '0');
            y_reg <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            x_reg <= x;
            y_reg <= y;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    sx <= x_reg(NF+NE);
    fx <= unsigned(x_reg(NF-1 downto 0));
    ex <= signed(x_reg(NF+NE-1 downto NF));
    
    sy <= y_reg(NF+NE);
    fy <= unsigned(y_reg(NF-1 downto 0));
    ey <= signed(y_reg(NF+NE-1 downto NF));

    mx <= unsigned('1' & fx);
    my <= unsigned('1' & fy);
    
    sz <= sx xor sy;
    mz_prev <= mx * my ;

    sx_ex <= signed('0' & '0' & ex);
    sx_ey <= signed('0' & '0' & ey);
    
    ez_prev <= sx_ex + sx_ey - EXC;

    process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            fz <= (others => '0');
            ez <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            if (ex = ZERO_E and fx = ZERO_F) or (ey = ZERO_E and fy = ZERO_F) then
                ez <= (others => '0');
                fz <= (others => '0');
            else
                if mz_prev(2*NF+1) = '1' then
                    fz <= mz_prev(2*NF downto NF+1);
                    ez_p2 <= ez_prev + 1;
                else
                    fz <= mz_prev(2*NF-1 downto NF);
                    ez_p2 <= ez_prev;
                end if;

                if ez_p2(NE+1) = '1' then
                    fz <= (others => '0');
                    ez <= (others => '0');
                elsif ez_p2(NE) = '1' then
                    fz <= (others => '1');
                    ez <= (others => '1');
                else
                    ez <= ez_p2(NE-1 downto 0);
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            z <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            z <= sz & std_logic_vector(ez) & std_logic_vector(fz);
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture behavioral;

Testbench:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use STD.TEXTIO.ALL;

entity fp_multiplier_testbench is
end entity fp_multiplier_testbench;

architecture fp_multiplier_testbench_arch of fp_multiplier_testbench is
    constant TCK:           time := 20 ns; -- periodo de reloj
    constant DELAY:         natural := 0; -- retardo de procesamiento del DUV
    constant WORD_SIZE_T:   natural := 28; -- tamaño de datos
    constant NE:            natural := 19; -- tamaño exponente
    constant NF:            natural := 8; 
    
    signal tb_rst: std_logic;
    signal tb_clk: std_logic := '0';
    signal x_file: unsigned(WORD_SIZE_T-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal y_file: unsigned(WORD_SIZE_T-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal z_file: unsigned(WORD_SIZE_T-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal z_del: unsigned(WORD_SIZE_T-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal z_duv: std_logic_vector(WORD_SIZE_T-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal z_del_aux: std_logic_vector(WORD_SIZE_T-1 downto 0):= (others => '0');
    signal ciclos: integer := 0;
    signal errores: integer := 0;
    file datos: text open read_mode is "C:/Users/lenovo/Documents/Sistemas digitales/TP2_ACUNA_MUL/tb/fmul_19_8.txt";
    
    component delay_gen is
        generic(
        N: natural:= 26;
        DELAY: natural:= 0
        );
        port(
        clk: in std_logic;
        A: in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
        B: out std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0)
        );
    end component;
    
begin
    tb_rst <= '0', '1' after 1 ns, '0' after 20 ns;
    
    -- Generacion del clock del sistema
    tb_clk <= not(tb_clk) after TCK / 2; -- reloj
    
    Test_Sequence: process
        variable l: line;
        variable ch: character := ' ';
        variable aux: integer;
    begin
        while not(endfile(datos)) loop
            wait until rising_edge(tb_clk);
            -- solo para debugging
            ciclos <= ciclos + 1;
            -- se lee una linea del archivo de valores de prueba
            readline(datos, l);
            -- se extrae un entero de la linea
            read(l, aux);
            -- se carga el valor del operando A
            x_file <= to_unsigned(aux, WORD_SIZE_T);
            -- se lee un caracter (es el espacio)
            read(l, ch);
            -- se lee otro entero de la linea
            read(l, aux);
            -- se carga el valor del operando B
            y_file <= to_unsigned(aux, WORD_SIZE_T);
            -- se lee otro caracter (es el espacio)
            read(l, ch);
            -- se lee otro entero
            read(l, aux);
            -- se carga el valor de salida (resultado)
            z_file <= to_unsigned(aux, WORD_SIZE_T); 
        end loop;
                    -- se cierra del archivo
            file_close(datos);
            -- Comparar el resultado calculado con el resultado esperado
            wait for TCK*(DELAY+1);
              -- esperar un ciclo de reloj para la operación
            assert false report
                "Fin de la simulacion" severity failure;
    end process Test_Sequence;
    
        -- Instanciacion del DUV
    DUV: entity work.multiplier_fp
        generic map(
            NE => NE,
            NF => NF
        )
        port map(
            rst => tb_rst,
            clk => tb_clk,
            x => std_logic_vector(x_file),
            y => std_logic_vector(y_file),
            z => z_duv
        );
    del: delay_gen
        generic map(WORD_SIZE_T, DELAY)
        port map(tb_clk, std_logic_vector(z_file), z_del_aux);
    z_del <= unsigned(z_del_aux);
 
    verificacion: process(tb_clk)
    begin  
        if rising_edge(tb_clk) then
            assert unsigned(z_duv) = z_del report
                "Error: Salida del DUV no coincide con referencia (salida del duv = " &
                integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(z_duv))) &
                ", salida del archivo = " &
                integer'image(to_integer(z_del)) & ")"
                severity warning;
            if unsigned(z_file) /= unsigned(z_duv) then
                errores <= errores + 1;
             end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture fp_multiplier_testbench_arch;


I tried doing this in the first process but it didn't work.
    process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            x_reg <= (others => '0');
            y_reg <= (others => '0');
            sx <= '0';
            fx <= (others => '0');
            ex <= (others => '0');
            sy <= '0';
            fy <= (others => '0');
            ey <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            x_reg <= x;
            y_reg <= y;
            sx <= x(NF+NE);
            fx <= unsigned(x(NF-1 downto 0));
            ex <= signed(x(NF+NE-1 downto NF));
            sy <= y(NF+NE);
            fy <= unsigned(y(NF-1 downto 0));
            ey <= signed(y(NF+NE-1 downto NF));
        end if;
    end process;

The file I'm using for the testbench is:
84968962 155420626 173820151 
90668818 133285648 133693439 
250809204 256927476 133693439 
187549860 94611700 215616381 
23010822 32328796 0 
123798214 247815052 267911167 
52729122 81107514 67285620 
196943838 58401408 188817973 
177811242 123779564 235013275 
218074150 22130300 173631585 
95745908 68678840 97840719 
118679016 88533372 133693439 
66156254 55045324 54619010 
137709142 86990176 158121833 
109323302 246582370 267911167 
201957382 145729724 12675974 
227644614 227468836 120122365 
267461922 74854648 267911167 
160887532 219930140 45815430 
187437080 83847962 204709845 
57041496 9677868 0 
64828680 208673576 206922205 
47813730 18169544 0 
32684096 74253976 40417822 
105796378 226450660 265666834 
108234738 188227786 229881652 


See [ask] and [mcve]. There is no specific question here and your waveform stimuli presents neither discernible input and result values nor are any expected results specified. Your "wrong" results can't be verified nor corrections validated.

I've updated my question and added some of the values in the file I'm using for the simulation , sorry

Please add the missing part delay_gen and the commands you use to build and run. -- What did you try to debug further, did you check intermediate values?

As sx and sy are simply "exporting" the topmost bit of the registers x_reg and y_reg, respectively, we need to look at the latter.
This is the relevant excerpt of your component under test:
    process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            x_reg <= (others => '0');
            y_reg <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            x_reg <= x;
            y_reg <= y;
        end if;
    end process;

The registers x_reg and y_reg are clocked by clk and store the input signals x and y, respectively.
In your test bench you assign x_file and y_file, respectively, to the input signals:
        port map(
            rst => tb_rst,
            clk => tb_clk,
            x => std_logic_vector(x_file),
            y => std_logic_vector(y_file),
            z => z_duv
        );

The test bench provides the values by these statements (irrelevant parts left out):
            wait until rising_edge(tb_clk);
            -- ...
            x_file <= to_unsigned(aux, WORD_SIZE_T);
            -- ...
            y_file <= to_unsigned(aux, WORD_SIZE_T);

Now let us decode the waveform diagram into a table for focus and convenience.



clock cycle #
x_file MSB...
y_file MSB...
sx
sy




1 (still in reset)
0...
1...
0
0


2
0...
0...
0
1


3
1...
1...
0
0


4
1...
0...
1
1


5
0...
0...
1
0


6
0...
1...
0
0



Analysis: Since the input values are provided after the clock edge, the registers take them at the next clock edge.

If you want to latch the input value one cycle earlier, you need to provide them before the clock edge. You could do this for example with these changes to your test bench (irrelevant parts left out):
    Test_Sequence: process
        -- ...
    begin
        wait for TCK / 4; -- This gives you some "phase".
        while not(endfile(datos)) loop
            -- remove this: wait until rising_edge(tb_clk);
            -- ...
            x_file <= to_unsigned(aux, WORD_SIZE_T);
            -- ...
            y_file <= to_unsigned(aux, WORD_SIZE_T);
            -- ...
            wait for TCK;
        end loop;
        -- ...
    end process Test_Sequence;


So "most of the results wrong" are for what values and what are the correct values for what input stimuli? How does the OP get the design specification to work and how can Stackoverflow readers tell what was required to fix what specific error(s)?

@user16145658 According to the OP's post the offset by one cycle is the main issue, and this is addressed and analyzed. -- There is also a possible suggestion how to get the expected timely behavior. Of course, this is only the first step in debugging the design. -- As you commented at the question, we cannot go deeper since input values and output results are missing.

"The problem is that I'm getting most of the results wrong." How do I write a good answer?, see the section Answer well-asked questions. How can future readers benefit from unclear questions with answers such as yours as a search resource? You could interact with the OP to clarify the question. It's only missing specifics.

I get two more wrong expected values by changing those lines you suggested

With @Sofia 's added fmul_19_8.txt content and the code as shown from the question you get one less error than the number of cycles which appears to be due to the clock occurring during reset. There is an error for every no reset stimulus response.
